# Energy costs and gains for creature growth at a molecular level

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

This is a long time scale creature - it experiences a thousand years in the fashion that we experience one.

It grows by pulling one neutron from a $C^{12}$ molecule and building it onto other carbon molecules to make $C^{14}$. Time frame for that isn't too important as the $C^{13}$ is stable. The $C^{11}$ decays with a fast half life of 20 min to $B^{11}$ and the $C^{14}$ decays to nitrogen with a half life near 6k years.

Energy changes:

- removing neutron from $C^{12}$
- adding neutron to make $C^{13}$ and $C^{14}$
- decay of $C^{11}$ to $B^{11}$
- decay of $C^{14}$ to N

Is it gaining or losing energy here?

Comment: this seems more like a physics question than a biology one

Comment: Yea probably, but it is for a xeno creature that works on those scales with that being one if its primary energy interactions. added physics tag

Comment: @Allan the issue being that while /for/ a xeno creature the question asks nothing about the creature. This is nothing but physics with a couple very loose relations.

Comment: should it be migrated from worldbuilding?

Comment: Worldbuilding incudes real physics as well, so as science. @OP it is a loss of energy, as self decay indicates it - they move from less stable state to more stable and emit energy in process - gamma, and particles with cerain velocity aka energy.  But men description of what happens in your q is a mess

Comment: I do enjoy the handwavium of "pulling one neutron".  This is so wildly unlikely for anything biological to do that it's breathtaking.

Comment: wave with one hand to pull it off, and wave with the other to add it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the masses of all those isotopes, for [Carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_carbon), [Boron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_boron), [Nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_nitrogen) and [neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron):

- $C^{11}$ = 11.01143260
- $C^{12}$ = 12
- $C^{13}$ = 13.00335483521
- $C^{14}$ = 14.003241988
- $B^{11}$ = 11.009305167
- $N^{14}$ = 14.00307400446
- $n^0$ = 1.00866491588

The process you describe is (neglecting the electrons emitted in the beta decays) $3 C^{12} \rightarrow  2 C^{11} + C^{14} \rightarrow 2 B^{11} + N^{14} $.

The initial mass is $3\cdot 12 = 36$, while the final mass is $2\cdot 11.009305167 + 14.00307400446 = 36.02168433846$.

Since we know that $E=mc^2$, the fact that the final mass is higher means that the whole process doesn't produce net energy, but rather absorbs it.

If you instead go for the path $3 C^{13} \rightarrow   C^{11} + 2 C^{14} \rightarrow B^{11} + 2 N^{14}$ you start with a mass of $3\cdot 13.00335483521=39.01006450563$ and finish with a mass of $11.009305167 + 2\cdot 14.00307400446 = 39.01545317592$, which is also slightly higher, thus also this chain doesn't produce net energy.

Comment: Thus this can only be its building blocks not its energy source.

Comment: The "process" absorbs *a lot* of energy, about 50.4 TJ / kg for the first "reaction". That's about the equivalent of 10,000 tons of TNT, or about the amount of electric power produced by a typical 600 MW reactor group of a nuclear power plant in a day.